# How to Make Moving Sprite Point Toward Mouse in P5?

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry, p5.js, vector-graphics

I was trying to make a program that pointed a sprite toward my mouse despite its displacement from the origin.

It rotates fine when it is at the origin, but obviously, when I start to move the sprite away, it thinks to rotate based on the origin and not it's position.

How can I make my rotation related to my sprites position properly? Here is my code:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  rectMode(CENTER)
}

function draw() {
    
    background(0);
    let posX = width/2;
    let posY = height/2;
  
    if (keyIsDown(87)) {y = y - 1;}
    if (keyIsDown(83)) {y = y + 1;}
    if (keyIsDown(65)) {x = x - 1;}
    if (keyIsDown(68)) {x = x + 1;}
    
    let angle = Math.atan2(mouseY-posY, mouseX-posX);
    translate(posX, posY);
    rotate(angle)
    square(x,y,100)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So now your character moves like I think you want to (regardless of the mouse position - the forward direction is always the top of screen):

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  rectMode(CENTER)
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    let posX = width/2;
    let posY = height/2;

    //I went back to the moving way of your character which was before, and i hope this is what you expect:
    let angle = Math.atan2(mouseY - posY - y, mouseX - posX - x);
    if (keyIsDown(87)) {y = y - 1;}
    if (keyIsDown(83)) {y = y + 1;}
    if (keyIsDown(65)) {x = x - 1;}
    if (keyIsDown(68)) {x = x + 1;}

    //And here is the same as was before:
    translate(posX + x, posY + y);
    rotate(angle);
    square(0,0,100);
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! It's actually not quite what I was looking for but another great movement system that I will definitely use later on. In the movement I'm looking for, I want the character to always look toward the mouse even if moving left and right. In this case, it seems like the character looks towards the mouse but the movement gets changed so that the forward direction is the mouse vector.

Comment: I know, but I thought that is what you wanted. You mean that by pressing the 'w' key, for example, your character walks up the screen, not towards the mouse?

Comment: In other words, you want your character to always move in the same direction, regardless of the mouse position?